# undefined function mochiweb_html:parse/1

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to use mochiweb in a module, but can't find a way to make the module 'aware' of mochiweb.

```
mochiweb_html:parse("<XML>").
```

This works fine in *erl*, but I keep getting `undefined function` when I use it inside a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question, it sounds like a code path problem.  as long as mochiweb_html.beam is in your code path, you can use any exported function.

running it from the erlang shell (erl) may have worked because the beam file was in your cwd.

for example:

```
# cd /home/blah/src/mochiweb/ebin; erl
1> code:where_is_file("mochiweb_html.beam").
"./mochiweb_html.beam"

# cd /tmp; erl
1> code:where_is_file("mochiweb_html.beam").
non_existing
```

make sure that the directory containing mochiweb_html.beam is in your code path.

to add it to your code path, use command lind args (-pa, -pz):

```
# erl -pa /home/blah/src/mochiweb/ebin
1> code:where_is_file("mochiweb_html.beam").
"/home/blah/src/mochiweb/ebin/mochiweb_html.beam"
```

or using the code module (code:add_patha, code:add_pathz):

```
# erl
1> code:where_is_file("mochiweb_html.beam").
non_existing
2> code:add_patha("/home/blah/src/mochiweb/ebin/").
true
3> code:where_is_file("mochiweb_html.beam").
"/home/blah/src/mochiweb/ebin/mochiweb_html.beam"
```